# screen cracked android - so I cannot gesture unlock

Tags: lock-screens, screen, samsung-galaxy-note-3, broken-screen

I have a fairly common issue: a screen damaged android phone. These devices are highly vulnerable to broken screens (this particular phone, the samsung galaxy note 3, had 2 replacement screens before this one) I refuse to purchase another to simply get my data.

As I read about it I am ***disgusted*** at the attitude of the data thieves at google: (I make no bones about it, it is laughable to call it "security" - it is simply deliberate data theft in the guise of obscurity - and I know this because I write systems that do much more security for far less damage)

But forget the disgust, for the purposes of this question just ignore it, just don't try to defend it, or censor that I wrote it. I know what I am talking about.

As I say, I am a developer on Android so I already had adb installed on my pc and already had usb debugging enabled:

First I tried this: 1) Since my Google Account was set up on the phone I went to Google "remote locking" service http:*www.android.com devicemanager* only to discover that while this service LOCKS phones it does not UNLOCK them (...?) (x ANDROID FAIL)

Secondly I tried to : 2) use adb to `adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key` but it is permission denied (x ANDROID FAIL)

Thirdly I tried to root the phone so I could use adb: 3) However even though I have *now* rooted the phone, I rooted it with the lock screen locked, so I cannot get the initial gesture unlock, to work to "confirm click" the root: (x ANDROID FAIL)

[image: my now able to "weirdly" use su]

Fourthly I tried : 4)  the tool "Android Control.exe" http: android-control.software.informer.com/ seems to show the most promise but it only replicates gestures in on gesture vector, i.e. if your unlock gesture changes direction (as mine does) then h will not work - i.e. more than a single direction in a swipe and you have no way in: (x ANDROID FAIL)

Fifthly I learnt : 5) I could use a VNC if I had installed the server on the phone before hand (x ANDROID FAIL)

So, my question is, while locked out of **my** property by a bunch of slack idiots who are paid far too much, can anyone suggest a way out other than the five ridiculous android fails tried and the with I want to wait to try:

Options 6) is to buy a [micro usb hdmi/ usb mouse dongle][3] but it is a lot of money for a device that I need to use only once to swipe only once

Comment: To do 2), you must run the adb shell as root.

Comment: .. that's why it is good to read 3)

Comment: So you executed the command **as root user** and it still returned no permission?

Comment: no, the phone `was` not rooted, the screen cracked, I `then rooted it` but I cannot confirm the rooting ona locked phone, because to be rooted because I have to physically accept a confirm box, on the phone, which I cannot get to

Comment: quite honestly why you cannot type in a numeric representation of the bloody gesture in adb is beyond me. there are 9 positions, name them 1-9 then you're done. adb gesture-unlock 34561 would do, have a timeout exponentially on response to rule out crack attempts - done.

Comment: That's because adb's logic is not that. It simply is a tool to use command-terminal of Android to execute commands, that GUIs execute at background, manually from your PC. You can use TWRP's File Manager to delete the file you want to delete (I don't know if other Custom Recoveries have File Managers).

Comment: bit off topic, but it would be trivial to send a gesture representation via the command line to data/system/gesture.key and then wait 180 seconds the offer to remove it via "y" if it is the correct gesture

Comment: doesn't TWRP have to be installed as an app on a already rooted phone?

Comment: @MrHeelis TWRP is a recovery, not an app. You install/flash it using ODIN and simply do the three-button-boot-to-recovery combination of `volume-up+home+power-on` and use it. Although I think TWRP is a touch-only recovery, so I would recommend CWM or PhilZ recovery (both allow button-only use.

Comment: GiantTree this sounds like the answer can you please write that as an answer, with some links and step by step break down of what said,  so I can accept it

Comment: I've heard that Note 3 supports OTG and OTG cable are way too cheap nowadays. Can you not grab one and combined with a standard PC mouse, use it to unlock the screen or do whatever you would using one finger touch? Also, use @ to notify somebody. @GiantTree wouldn't have received your comment about requesting a formal answer.

Comment: @GiantTree AHH.. That's so true. TWRP works with touch screen. I feel really so... Does CWM have file manager?

Comment: @SarpSTA I don't know, I haven't used CWM in a while. I know PhilZ recovery has (I'm using it on my S6 Edge).

Comment: @SarpSTA, well turns out Philz does *not* have a built in file manager like TWRP, but an always active adb daemon in root mode, which helps far more than just a file manager.

Comment: MrHeelis You must pay attention to it. Install the Philz Custom recovery and use adb commands to remove the file. @GiantTree turned it into one really good answer.

Comment: @SarpSTA It is not mandatory though, but if you genuinely think that an answer is really good, *make sure to upvote it*. It gives a better signal to others that the post is helpful. Just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### WARNING: Follow these instructions only, if you are aware of the risks!

#### I am not responsible for any hard-/soft-brick! Proceed only if you know what you are doing!

#### Possible loss of warranty by triggering KNOX flags, flash counters etc.!!!

#### READ THE ENTIRE ANSWER BEFORE FOLLOWING ANY OF THESE STEPS!!!

## Install CWM and Philz recovery.

If you not already have a custom recovery installed:

Use ODIN to flash a third party recovery. I recommend PhilZ recovery, because you can navigate through all menus using only the buttons on your device:

**First:** Download *ODIN*, *CWM recovery* and *PhilZ touch recovery* from this XDA-thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-3/general/n900-one-guide-t3252033 (you may want to read that post, too).
You will need to install Philz with CWM, because CWM does not feature a file manager and Philz can only be flashed through another non-stock recovery.

**Next:** Shutdown your device and boot into the bootloader.
You may use `adb reboot bootloader` or the combination: Power + Home + Volume-DOWN

**Install CWM (this will trigger any flash counter, KNOX warranty void bit etc., only proceed if there is a way to undo this or you will most certainly loose your warranty):**

1. Unpack ODIN and launch the application.
2. In ODIN: Click on the *PDA* button and select the CWM `.tar` archive
3. Now, connect your phone to your PC and click the *Start* button.

You now have CWM installed!

4. Your phone should reboot automatically, so after it finished booting, copy the Philz recovery `.zip` onto your device's storage. You can use either the Windows Explorer or `adb push <zip file> /sdcard/` for this. I'm not sure if the Windows Explorer method works with a locked screen, though.
5. Reboot into the CWM recovery by either shutting down your device and pressing the combination `Power + Home + Volume-UP` or using `adb reboot recovery`
6. Use your volume up/down buttons to select `install zip from sdcard` and confirm it by pressing the power button (it's possible to install a zip through sideload, but sideloading is not very reliable from others' and my experience)
7. Select your philz recovery `.zip` file and confirm to flash it.
8. Reboot the recovery by going into the `Advanced` menu and selecting `reboot recovery`
9. You will now be greeted by the Philz recovery screen.

## Do all sorts of root commands:

1. Use your PC to run `adb shell`. You will automatically be in root mode (check `whoami` -> `root`)
2. Remove the `.key` files that prevent you from unlocking your device. (`rm /data/system/gesture.key`)
3. Reboot the device by simply selecting `Reboot System Now` and pressing the power button.

You should now have no screen lock, as Android is unable to find the key that is used to compare your input gesture to and will fall back to either no lock at all or *swipe to unlock*.

<sub>I can confirm that this guide is working with the Galaxy S6 Edge (SM-G925F), if the proper files are used.</sub>